# how to instantiate entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have an MVC project where I see Entity Framework is instantiated like this
in every controller in the constructor.

```
AvailableStock db = new AvailableStock ();
```

Is this the right way to do it? Also where should I put
some business logics for instance update the stock?
Following code update the stock of a product. Where
do I put this piece of code? Do I create a separate business
layer and add the code there?

```
stock = db.RoseBush.Where( x=>x.id == Id )
stock.status = StockStatus.Out;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET MVC project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Usually it is not a good idea to keep a DbContext object alive for a longer period of time.**

If you create a DbContext object, a connection with the database is opened. All objects that you fetch are kept locally in the DbContext, so that it can detect changes. If you use Find to query the same object again, it is not asked from the database, you get the local copy again. So if you change a fetched object and use Find to fetch it again, you get the object inclusive the changes. To get the original object you have to use Select.

So while your DbContext exists, it might be that you will be missing changes that other people made to the same object (when using Find), or you might lose your own changes, if you use Select. Besides, quite often databases need to do some internal housekeeping that is postponed as long as database connections are open.

Conclusion: it is not wise to keep the DbContext open for a longer period of time.

Whether it is wise to create a DbContext object in the constructor of your controller, depends on the lifetime expectancy of your controller. If you create the controller, and keep it alive for seconds, maybe even minutes, then it might not be wise to keep the DbContext alive all the time.

Quite often people wrap the database into a repository class that hides that the data is stored in a database, it hides the structure of the tables, and it hides whether the database is contacted using entity framework, or plain old SQL.

Users of the repository (= software, not operators) only know that if they decide to save the changes, the data is stored somewhere, and the next time they create the repository object again, the saved data can be fetched again. The user of the repository doesn't know, and doesn't have to know that the data is stored in a database. For all they know, it could also be stored in a CSV-file, or XML, JSon, whatever, they don't care.

The nice thing about this repository pattern, is that you can separate the internal database structure from the interface that the users of your repository need. You can give different users different repositories: some users of your repository need only to query information. Other users might want to Add or Update information, while only few might need the ability to delete items, add and remove tables, etc.

Another advantage of a repository is that it is easy to unit test: you don't need a real database in the repository for the unit tests, Dictionaries that hold the tables will suffice.

The interface of the repository is usually such, that users create the repository and keep it alive for a longer time. They only have the functions needed for their purpose. Things like changing tables, deleting items etc are usually kept out of the repository.

```
interface ISchoolRepository
{
    ICollection<School> GetAllSchools();
    ICollection<School> GetSchoolsByCity(string city);

    ICollection<Teacher> GetAllTeachers();
    ICollection<Teacher> GetTeachersBySchoolId(int schoolId);
    ICollection<Teacher> GetTeachersWithTheirStudents(int schoolId);
    ...
}

class SchoolRepository : ISchoolRepository
{
    // Hide the internal database structure:
    private class SchoolDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<School> Schools {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
    }

    public ICollection<Teacher> GetTeachersBySchoolId(int schoolId)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new SchoolDbContext())
        {
            return dbContext.Teachers.Where(teacher => teacher.SchoolId == schoolId)
                                     .ToList();
        }
    }

    ... // etc
}
```

If you need several different SchoolRepositories, each with different capabilities, then of course the SchoolDbContext is not a private class, it will be a separate class.

If for some reason you need to change the internal structure of your database, or decide not to use entity framework anymore and use plain SQL, users of your structure won't notice the changes. For unit tests, you can create a simple implementation of ISchoolRepository that uses Dictionaries as tables. Usually the databases for unit tests are not that big, so the inefficiency is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks! I took a while to respond. But your answer improved my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your questions is "it depends".  Without more information, it's hard to say.  You instantiate your database model when you need it.  The controller constructor is called on every request, so instantiating the model there may be appropriate if you know that every action method in your controller will use it.  Perhaps more typically, however, not every request needs an instance of the database--in which case you're instantiating it, doing nothing with it, and then disposing of it, which doesn't make much sense.

As for updating the database, this might typically be done in a controller POST method.  However, most would advocate for keeping your controllers lean, which would call for a separate business layer that does the actual updating and is called from the controller.  This layer would also be responsible for generating the GET data needed for your views.

Hopefully this helps.  Assuming your questions relate to ASP.NET MVC, I'd recommend going through some tutorials there as a way to help clarify your questions further.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you recommend any high quality tutorials/blogs around these? When I search 100s of them are coming and am not sure which would be the best ones.

Comment: None in particular.  As with everything else, the top Google hits tend to be the better ones.  If you want to find something tailored to your scenario, consider EF Code First vs. EF DB First, and of course .NET Core vs. .NET Standard.